# Bootstrap glyphicons don't render properly when using local css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a weird problem.

If I reference bootstrap css file from local host, this

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></span>
```

is rendered like this

[image]

but if I reference https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

is rendered correctly, like this

[image]

This makes no sense. The files are identical. I refreshed the cache as well (Ctrl+F5).

Anyone knows on top of their head what this could be?

Comment: The file css may be same but the font files might be different.

Comment: I just copied the fonts and now it works. I have no idea what happened. I have a hard time believing they got corrupted.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked! Cheers!